# Call single public function of a class without using its name

Tags: c++, reflection

Is it possible to invoke the function of a class based on the fact that it is the only public one ? What I mean:

Something like:

```cpp
double res = MyClass().myFunction(n);
```

becomes

```cpp
double res = MyClass()[0](n);
```

[Ideally I would have liked to call the function using a string with its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442101/calling-a-function-using-a-string-containing-the-functions-name):

```cpp
double res = MyClass().reflection("myFunction")(n);
```

But it seems not possible without wasting at least twice the ink to write the function name (function pointer and corresponding string in a map).

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Depends on what you actually need, but you also can easily realize such call using a lambda function defined on the fly (capture of local variables is possible without need for extra parameters).

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload the call operator of the class. This is commonly called a Functor:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int operator()(int param) const {
        return functionName(param);
    }

    int functionName(int param) const { return param; }
};

MyClass c;
int returnVal = c(3);
```

Edit addressing `const` comment:

The function and operator do not need to be `const`. You should mark functions `const` whenever the function does not modify the state of the object. This gives more information to people calling the function and is particularly important in multi-threaded applications. If the function you are calling is not const you can remove the const from the overload.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration) for more info.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL You can do anything you want in the body of the overloaded operator and you can replace `int param` with any arguments you want. It works just like a function. You can call other functions from there as well.

Comment: I trust you but I get ```error: passing ‘const MyClass’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL In your case, you'd need a call operator overload as shown here, which takies a parameter of type `const std::string&`, which is used then to translate to the actual function call (e.g. using a `std::map<std::string,std::function<void()>`. If you need additional (input / output) parameters add them as needed, but you must have a function / operator call signature, which fit's for all the functions you want to call that way. C++ deosn't really support reflection.

Comment: That means that the instance of the class you are calling the operator on is const and you did not mark the operator as const.

Comment: @DeanJohnson Consider expanding your example with another one following my comment. That will less confuse the OP, what they can do with the call operator overload (functor).

Comment: OP seems to want to index the methods like `my_class[2]("some value")`. They did mention that there is only one public function, but that makes the whole `[]` syntax unnecessary. So, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can get something close to what you wrote by overloading the `[]` operator:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass
{
public:
  double operator [] (int n)
  {
    return functionName (n);
  }

private:
  double functionName (int n)
  {
    return n + 1;
  }
};


int main ()
{
  int n = 1;
  double res = MyClass ()[n];
  std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

See the result [here](https://onlinegdb.com/X4yPYSPOM).

Notice tha [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), the parameter passed to `[]` is shown to be of size_t, but I don't think that is a requirement by the standard. I was able to make it work for `std::string` as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class MyClass
{
public:
  std::string operator [] (std::string n)
  {
    return functionName (n);
  }

private:
  std::string functionName (std::string n)
  {
    return n + '1';
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  std::string n = "test";
  std::string res = MyClass ()[n];
  std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;

}
```

See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/uCYrC7L2_)

Comment: very nice as well +1

Comment: The array subscript operator used here is often defined with `size_t` as the parameter, but that is just a convention because of what the operator is usually used for (indexing into containers). That is not required by the language standard.

Comment: _@Ari_ _"But interestingly, I was able to make it work even for std::string!"_ Yup! Proven since the very 1st version of `std::map<KeyType,ValueType>` once was instantiated with the type `std::string` as `KeyType` ;-) And the same for the call operator overload `operator()(const std::string& fnName)` BTW.

Comment: *"the parameter passed to [] should be of size_t"* there is no such requirement.